# A question about conditional expectation involving independence

Tags: probability, independence, conditional-expectation

If the vector $(u,v)$ is independent of the vector $x$, then I would like to show that
$$E(u|x,v)= E(u|v)$$

The only thing I can derive from the definitions is that if $(u,v)$ is independent of $x$, then $E( (u,v) | x)= E((u,v))$.

I can no longer attack this problem!

Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following definitions:
$$
\begin{align}
E(u|x,v) &= \int u \: p(u|x,v) \: du\\
E(u|v) &=   \int u \: p(u|v) \: du.
\end{align}
$$
I.e., if we could show that for $p(u|x,v) = p(u|v)$, we were done. Now we have:
$$
\begin{align}
p(u|xv) &= \frac{p(u,x|v)}{p(x|v)}\\
        &= \frac{p(u|v)p(x|v)}{p(x|v)}\\
        &= p(u|v).
\end{align}
$$
The first equality is the definition of conditional probability, the second equality is because of independence. And we are done.

Maybe the second equality needs some clarification: We want to show that under the presumption of independence between $(u,v)$ and $x$, i.e. $p(u,v,x) = p(u,v)p(x)$, it follows that $p(u,x|v) = p(u|v)p(x|v)$. This can be seen as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
p(u,x|v) &= \frac{p(u,v,x)}{p(v)}\\
         &= \frac{p(u,v)p(x)}{p(v)}\\
         &= p(u|v)\frac{p(x)p(v)}{p(v)}\\
         &= p(u|v)\frac{p(x,v)}{p(v)}\\
         &= p(U|v)p(x|v),
\end{align}
$$
and we are done.